# Property 'myfunc' was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

I don't know why but this error **Property 'myfunc' was accessed during render but is not defined on instance** is keeps on showing.
I am sharing my Html and js code.

```
const ListRenderingApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      todos: [
        { text: 'Learn JavaScript' },
        { text: 'Learn Vue' },
        { text: 'Build something awesome' }
      ]
    }
  },
  method : {
    myfunc(){
      console.log('drats')
    }
  }
}
Vue.createApp(ListRenderingApp).mount('#list-rendering')
```

And the Html files code is

```
<div id="list-rendering" class="demo">
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      {{ todo.text }}
    </li>
    
  </ol>
  <button v-on:click="myfunc"> Click me</button>
</div>
```

I am very new to Vue.js. So, if anyone can please help me with this question.

Comment: it should be `methods` instead of `method`: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods

Answer (score 0):

I understood the error. And came up with the solution as well.

Firstly, In the ***ListRenderingApp*** after the data function. It should be `methods`. And secondly, in the console.log() statement it should be `console.log(this.todos)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    todos: [
        { text: 'Learn JavaScript' },
        { text: 'Learn Vue' },
        { text: 'Build something awesome' }
      ]
  },
  methods : {
    myfunc() {
      console.log('drats')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      {{ todo.text }}
    </li>
  </ol>
  <button v-on:click="myfunc"> Click me</button>
</div>
```